# Copy Values from Two Rows Up and Insert Below

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet and some codeing that inserts a new line under a specific word in a table of data.

I need to copy the row two lines up and paste it into the new line.
then i need to swap some of the column contents round.

Current code :

```
Sub Insert()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row
        For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
            If Cell.Value <> Cell.Offset(1, 0) Then
                If Cell.Value = "Lunch" Or Cell.Value = "Unscheduled" Then
                 Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Cell.Row - 1).Copy
                 Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Cell.Row + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
    End Sub
```

I need to get the data to then copy from specific rows above. I have tried adding in this code but it doesnt work:

```
        Range(Cell.Address).Offset(-1, 3).Value = Range(Cell.Address).Offset(1, 1).Value
```

EG:
[image: What I Need it to do]

Then i need it to repeat this all the way down.
So essentially the code needs to do this
Range A3:D3 would be copied into A5:D5

F4 would be copied to E5

G3 would be copied into F5

The data would always be in the two rows above the line I need it.
Hope this makes sense.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do the original Open times always start before lunch and end after lunch ?

Comment: Yes they do, my code adds in a new line under each lunch. I tried adding in offset line of code but i cannot get it to work.

Comment: Ive amended my question as ive managed to get the row copied i just cannot get the cells above to work with offset. Please have a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
Sub Insert()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Cell As Range, i As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row
        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            Set Cell = .Cells(i, "D")
            If Cell.Value <> Cell.Offset(1, 0) Then
                ' Comparing cell value w/o case sensitive
                If VBA.StrComp(Cell.Value, "Lunch", 1) * VBA.StrComp(Cell.Value, "Unscheduled", 1) = 0 Then
                    .Rows(i + 1).Insert
                    .Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
                    .Cells(i + 1, "E").Value = .Cells(i, "F").Value
                    .Cells(i + 1, "F").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "G").Value
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. just copies the cells two up and it only does it one at a time i have to keep clicking run macro to get it to keep doing each line. It also does it at the end of the data and not inserting new lines.

If i can keep my code and work out how to add in the copying the rows above that would fix the issue, any ideas on three lines of code to copy to my new line from my original code?

Comment: I have updated the code. Inserting row will shift rows down. You need to use looping in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your original data without the added lines

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub convert()

    Dim dict As Object, k As String, wb As Workbook
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim lunchStart, lunchEnd
    Dim newrow As Long, n As Long, ar
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
         lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
         ar = .Range("A1:F" & lastrow)
         
         ' scan down sheet for lunch or unscheduled
         For r = 2 To lastrow
            k = ar(r, 1) & ":" & ar(r, 2) ' key
            If ar(r, 4) = "Lunch" Or ar(r, 4) = "Unscheduled" Then
                If dict.exists(k) Then
                    MsgBox "Duplicate Open Time row " & r, vbCritical
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    dict.Add k, r
                End If
            End If
         Next
         
         ' scan up adding records
         For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            If ar(r, 4) = "Open Time" Then
                k = ar(r, 1) & ":" & ar(r, 2) ' key
                
                If dict.exists(k) Then
                
                    lunchStart = ar(dict(k), 5)
                    lunchEnd = ar(dict(k), 6)
                    newrow = dict(k) + 1 ' add below
                    
                    ' check if times span lunch
                    ' start before lunch start and end after lunch start
                    ' or start before lunch end and end afer lunch end
                    If ((ar(r, 5) < lunchStart) And (ar(r, 6) > lunchStart)) Or _
                       ((ar(r, 5) < lunchEnd) And (ar(r, 6) > lunchEnd)) Then
                       
                        ' insert line below lunch
                        .Rows(newrow).Insert
                        .Rows(newrow).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        n = n + 1
                        ' copy
                        For c = 1 To 6
                           .Cells(newrow, c) = ar(r, c)
                        Next
                        
                         ' make existing end time start of lunch
                        .Cells(r, 6) = ar(dict(k), 5)
                        
                        ' make new row start time end of lunch
                        .Cells(newrow, 5) = ar(dict(k), 6)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
         Next
    End With
    
    MsgBox n & " rows added", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Ive tried this but nothing happens, and comes up with "0 lines added" :(

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome has upated their answer and works how i need it! Thanks so much for your help too.